# DirectX9 Скриншот игры в полном экране

Tags: c++, dll, directx, хук

Всем привет, хотел тут задать вопрос, в надежде, что помогут.
Я недавно хотел сделать программу которая скринит экран игры, я все прочитал, смотрел некоторые статьи, ну и вот пришел к такому коду

```
D3DDEVICE_CREATION_PARAMETERS cparams;
RECT rect;

m_pDevice->GetCreationParameters(&cparams);
GetWindowRect(cparams.hFocusWindow, &rect);

IDirect3DSurface9* pBackBuffer, *pSurfTemp;
HRESULT hRes = m_pDevice->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &pBackBuffer);
hRes = m_pDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(rect.right - rect.left, rect.top - rect.bottom, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &pSurfTemp, NULL );
hRes = m_pDevice->GetRenderTargetData(pBackBuffer, pSurfTemp);

D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile("D:\\output.jpg", D3DXIFF_JPG, pBackBuffer, NULL, NULL);
SAFE_RELEASE(pBackBuffer);
SAFE_RELEASE(pSurfTemp);
```

Я инжектю в процесс DLL, после перехватываю EndScene, и получаю каждый фрейм с LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9. 
Ну вот, в чем дело, он как бы скринит игру, но после скриншота крашиться игра и вылетает, но скриншот получается, не знаю в чем весь сыр-бор, если есть кто знает как решить эту проблему, буду очень им благодарен.

Comment: если закоментировать                                                                                                                     SAFE_RELEASE(pBackBuffer);
SAFE_RELEASE(pSurfTemp);  крашит?

Comment: а настоящий EndScene вы вызываете?

Comment: Еще у вас 'pSurfTemp' получается лишняя, потому что в файл вы сохраняете экранный буфер напрямую. Видимо имелось в виду сохранять таки временную поверхность.